# SQL Server 2014 Linked Server Performance issue

Tags: performance, blob, sql-server-2014, linked-server

When I add linked server (SQL Server 2012 or earlier versions) to SQL Server 2014 and try just to make plain select from linked server table like (`select id ,image from [linkedserver].[dbname].[schema].[tablename]`) I have performance impact.

Image column is blob and 200 records, each 50 kb blob data (summary 10 mb) query executes some 1 minute or so.

If I install SQL Server 2012 on the same server and add the same remote server as linked server and execute the same query I have 20 time better result (2-3 seconds)

I try to analyze query, also include statistics , but with no positive result.
Is it a SQL Server 2014 specific bug ?